# Get Referral URL on page load in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I get the URL of current page on `onPageLoad()` event.

```
Dim URL = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString
```

I got the URL on button click, but I need to get the result on PageLoad itself.

Can any one suggest me on this case?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use it in `Page_Load`. But first You have to check if `UrlReferrer` isn't `nothing`.

There is example :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
  Dim URL As String = ""
  If Request.UrlReferrer IsNot Nothing Then
    URL = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString()
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I rarely build with VB. I use C#. However, There is no reason that Request.UrlReferrer would not be available in the Page_Load method in VB. It's available in C#.

Comment: If you need to say to something to the OP about tagging or other uses of SO, add a comment or edit the post.  Adding that to your answer is inappropriate.